# Space after reading in HTML content and echoing it

Tags: php, html, model-view-controller

I have an index.php-file, which will echo the string with the returned .html-file prepared by the function which is called in the index.php-file

index.php:

```
require_once('functions.php'); 
echo create_page();
```

functions.php:

```
function create_page() {
    $result = file_get_contents('index.html');
    return $result;
}
```

The problem is that everytime, the html is generated with this functions, I have a gap at the bottom of the page.

If I include several .html-pages into a .html-page with `str_replace`, a gap is at the top of every replacement.

If I display the .html-file by double-clicking it, it will be displayed without a gap at the bottom.

What am I doing wrong here?

There are no additional echos in the script.

Comment: What do you mean by a "gap"? Is that really the full `create_page()` function? It seems that it just loads the file's contents but then does nothing with it.

Comment: Sorry, I#ve forgotten to add the return to the create_page_function. With "gap" I mean that there are line-breaks at the top of the page (a white gap before the first div-element of the .html-page starts)

Comment: It seems, that the require_once-function will add the space. If I comment it out, there will be no space anymore.

Comment: Check the very end of your functions.php file. Make sure that the `?>` ends at exactly the ">" and there is no space or new line following it.

Comment: Or you can just remove the `?>` completely. Check also that the starting `<?php` tag is exactly at the start of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Here ist the soluton:

**Don't allow BOM in your texteditor-settings!**

The BOM could not be interpreted from the browser, so he added the gap at the bottom of every file which has BOM enabled...

Hope it helps someone else!

Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Check your php files, I bet they contain some new lines / spaces / tabs / other-white psace characters after php closing tag (`?>`). The best is to omit this closing tag, then every whitespace from the end of file will be treated as php source (harmless) and will not produce any output.